# Powershell Replace with Back References and Local Variable

Tags: regex, powershell, backreference

I'm trying to replace a pattern using a string that is concatenation of back references and local variable:

```
(Get-Content $nuspecPath) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "(<version>).+(<\/version>)", "`$1$version`$2"} | Set-Content $nuspecPath
```

Expected: `<version>2.0-preview</version>`

Actual: `2.0-preview</version>`

However, if I add space between variables like "`$1 $version`$2", I get `<version> 2.0-preview </version>` as expected.

Thoughts?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hmm, this works for me as you originally have it on PowerShell v4.  But when I run into an issue like this I usually solve it with curly braces e.g. ${1}

```
$version = '2.0-preview'
"<version>1.0.0.0</version>" -replace "(<version>).+(<\/version>)", "`${1}$version`$2"
```

By putting the variable name in curly braces, PowerShell can tell where one variable ends and another begins.  Also, confirmed that your original approach does indeed not work on one of my PowerShell v3 systems.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like somehow it's trying to include what's after 1 to be part of the back reference...your solution works fine and I read on another thread that named reference also works. :)

Comment: if you use `single quotes`, you don't need to escape the `$`, which is slightly simpler. Also the curkies are optional. in the above example, the replace string would be `'$1$version$2'`